# Change the position of div when re-showing it after hiding

Tags: jquery, css

Am creating a Facebook like chat application.(Say for example am chatting with 4 users)
Loginuser : Me
chattinguser-1:radmin
chattinguser-2:admin
chattinguser-3:orderingfacility
chattinguser-4:Ref.Provider

if i close chatting with radmin the adjacent chat div will move by side of closed div.

## Question

Am not disposing the div while user close chat.Just hide that div.so that the previous conversations remains in it while re-open it.
My problem is if i re-open the closed div by $(div).show() method it opens at the position where it was created first.I need to re-open that div after all div's that present
Am attaching a image describing the above[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the divs share a common parent you can try something like that:

```
$(div).show().appendTo($(div).parent());
```

I've included some example code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/ujdRF/7/

Comment: The `append`/`appendTo` methods don't automatically `clone` the element. An element can only have one path in the DOM, thus `append`ing it simply moves the element unless you `.clone`d it specifically. This may work, assuming `div` in this case is a reference to the DOM element/jQuery object of the hidden `div`. **edit:** Then again, OP didn't even show any code, normally just `.show()` should display the element in its original position if it wasn't moved/removed from the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the jquery function detach http://api.jquery.com/detach/ instead of just hiding it. Detach will remove the div from the DOM, but you can reattach the div container again, if you want to reuse it.

Comment: With a combination of using .insertAfter() http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/ this may work.